# How to link ta-lib in codeblocks (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, codeblocks, ta-lib

I have installed ta-lib in my ubuntu 14.04 as mentioned in the official documentation

```
extract tar.gz
./configure
./make
./make install
```

It installed ta-lib in `/usr/local/include/ta-lib`. I then added the header to talib alone `#include <ta-lib/ta_libc.h>` and compiled the code without error. but when I added the ta-lib sample codes

```
    #include <ta-lib/ta_libc.h>
    TA_RetCode retCode;
    retCode = TA_Initialize( );
    if( retCode != TA_SUCCESS )
    printf( "Cannot initialize TA-Lib (%d)!\n", retCode );
    else
    {
        printf( "TA-Lib correctly initialized.\n" );

        /* ... other TA-Lib functions can be used here. */

        TA_Shutdown();
    }
```

it gave an **undefined** error which I know was due to linking problem in codeblocks. So I manually added `ta-lib` in `project>build options> linker settings>link libraries` and `-lta-lib` to `other linker options` but now its giving this error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lta-lib
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
./configure
./make
./make install
```

will not install the package.

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

will install it. That is probably what you did.

> It installed ta-lib in /usr/local/include/ta-lib

Not exactly. It installed the library's header files under
`/usr/local/include/ta-lib` and it installed the static and shared
libraries under `/usr/local/lib`.

> I manually added ta-lib in project>build options> linker settings>link libraries 
>   and -lta-lib to other linker options

Those are alternative ways of doing the same thing. Both them will cause
the option `-lta-lib` to be passed to the linker, so your linker commandline
would show this option twice.

That option directs the linker to search for a shared library called `libta-lib.so` or, failing
that, a static library called `libta-lib.a` in each of the linker search
directories that you have specified, if any, and then in its default search
directories.

You have specified no linker search directories, but that is OK, because
`/usr/local/lib`, where the libraries are installed, *is* one of the linker's
default search directories.

The linker nevertheless complains that it cannot find a library for the option
`-lta-lib` because the shared library installed in `/usr/local/lib` is
`libta_lib.so` and the static library is `libta_lib.a`. Not `libta-lib.{so|a}`.

So :-

- Replace `ta-lib` with `ta_lib` in **Build options** -> **Linker settings** ->
  **Link libraries**
- Delete `-lta-lib` from **Build options** -> **Linker settings** ->
  **Other linker options**

Comment: Thanks you were right about the `sudo make install` and `ta_lib` now its compiling without any error